# How to create a pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

Imagine I have this table:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
------------------------------
   111         X        10
   111         Y        12
```

How can I query this table to show the results like these:

```
Column A |     X     |      Y
-----------------------------------
   111         10           12
```

Comment: What exactly is not clear after reading the many online examples of the `pivot` operator?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Note that although pivoting inside SQL server is functional and can help in certain situations, if you exceed around 10 pivots (columns) then performance will drop like a rock.

Comment: @ChrisLively - Thanks so much for this useful info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can perform this via a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can use either a static PIVOT where you know the number of columns that you want to rotate or you can use a dynamic PIVOT

Static Pivot (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ccae/1))

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  select *
  from t1
) x
pivot
(
  min(columnc)
  for columnb in ([X], [Y])
) p
```

Dynamic Pivot (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ccae/2))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(columnb) 
                    from t1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT columna, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select *
                from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(ColumnC)
                for ColumnB in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both versions will give the same results.  The second works when you have an unknown number of columns that will be transformed.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ColumnA INT, ColumnB CHAR(1), ColumnC INT)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (111, 'X', 10), (111, 'Y', 12)

SELECT  *
FROM    @tbl
PIVOT   
(
    MAX(ColumnC) FOR ColumnB IN ([X], [Y])
) pvt
```