# MySQL query where data shown in rows and not columns

Tags: mysql

I need to find the customerIDs of all customers who have ordered a certain quantity of particular products. For example, I want to get all customerIDs who have ordered 2 or more cheese or 5 or more bread. This should give me 1,4 and 3

```
customerID  product     qty
1           cheese      3
1           bread       2
2           cheese      1
2           pizza       4
3           bread       10
3           tomato      4
4           cheese      2
```

It would be much easier if my table structure was altered to have a column for cheese, bread, pizza, bread and tomato. Unfortunately this isn't possible.

EDIT: The customerID/product combo is unique. I would also like to be able to search for when all conditions are met. So, where 3 or more cheese AND 2 or more bread.

Comment: How long is the list of products?

Comment: @PM77-1 long ... like 200,000 rows

Comment: How long is the list that your search criteria is based upon?

Comment: @PM77-1 The original table contains about 200,000 rows. This is made up of about 50,000 unique customerIDs

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I'm interested whether the maximum number of products (and their quantities) to use in a single query is known.

Comment: Ah, OK. There are about 300 products that could be queried (it will never in reality be more than 10 ever queried in one go though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62079/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-christopherib).

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11230759/1726419

Comment: See [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) for possible solutions.

Comment: is the pair `customerID,product` unique to the table?

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes, they are

Comment: @christopherib I recommend adding that information to the question because if the pair is unique, then Usman's answer is sufficient but if it's not then you need to use `group by ... having`

Comment: @FuzzyTree Thanks, will do this now. Usman's solution is perfect .. but I would like to be able to specify a query where any or all of the conditions are met. His works perfectly for any but not for all

Comment: @christopherib adding the following to Usman's answer will give you what you need for the `and` scenario: `group by CustomerId having count(*) = 2` . also remove `distinct` from the query

Comment: @FuzzyTree Thank you for the guidance. If I try this then I get no results.

Comment: @FuzzyTree I have created a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfe53/2

Comment: @christopherib your fiddle does not contain any customers where both conditions are true. if you correct the data you'll get a row back see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d8ab7/2

Comment: @FuzzyTree Hmm, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d8ab7/3 should give me customerID 3 but it's not showing anything

Comment: @christopherib you need to use `or` (instead of `and`) in your `where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct customerID from Products
where (product = 'cheese' and qty >= 2) or (product = 'bread' and qty >= 5);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question, please don't simply post some code. Please explain why this code works so that the questioner (OP) can use this information for other similar problems in future.

Comment: Hi, this works well. Can you suggest how I can run a query that meets both conditions rather than just one? Using "and" instead of "or" doesn't work

Comment: @christopherib can you explain a bit more that what exactly do you want? I think I have given answer of your original question.

Comment: @worldofjr I'll take care of it next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.customerID,
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.product='cheese' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) as cheese,
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.product='bread' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) as bread
FROM t
GROUP BY t.customerID
HAVING cheese>=2
OR bread>=5;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3fc4/22)

Or move them to the HAVING clause for clarity

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3fc4/23)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** My bad... I misread the specification. The examples below returns customers that had 'cheese' qty>=2 **AND** 'bread' qty >=5. The specification was for **OR** rather than **AND**.

Here's an example of one approach (out of several viable approaches) to returning <strike>the specified</strike> a resultset that wasn't specified... customers that had BOTH cheese qty>=2 AND bread qty>=5:

```
SELECT a.customer_id
  FROM ( SELECT p.customer_id 
           FROM mytable p
          WHERE p.product         = 'cheese'
          GROUP BY p.customer_id
         HAVING SUM(p.qty)        >= 2
       ) a
  JOIN ( SELECT q.customer_id 
           FROM mytable q
          WHERE q.product         = 'bread'
          GROUP BY q.customer_id
         HAVING SUM(q.qty)        >= 5
       ) b
    ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

I've assumed you wanted to check the `qty` for a given product and given customer as the "total" qty, from all of the matching rows, not just checking for an individual row with qty over the specified value. If you only want to check qty on individual rows, then remove the predicate on the aggregate i.e. `HAVING SUM(qty) >= n`, and add a predicate in the WHERE clause `AND qty >= n`.

**EDIT** To get the result of customers that had EITHER, we could use a similar approach, getting the list of customers that had cheese qty>=1, and combining that with the list of customer that had bread qty>=5, and get a distinct list.

```
  ( SELECT p.customer_id 
      FROM mytable p
     WHERE p.product         = 'cheese'
     GROUP BY p.customer_id
    HAVING SUM(p.qty)        >= 2
  ) 
  UNION 
  ( SELECT q.customer_id 
      FROM mytable q
     WHERE q.product         = 'bread'
     GROUP BY q.customer_id
    HAVING SUM(q.qty)        >= 5
  )
```

---

There are some other approaches. You specifically asked about changing "rows" into "columns". The term we usually use to refer to that type of operation is "pivot" or "pivot table".

Here's an example of that approach:

```
SELECT t.customer_id
     , SUM(IF(t.product= 'cheese'  ,t.qty,NULL)) AS `qty_cheese`
     , SUM(IF(t.product= 'bread'   ,t.qty,NULL)) AS `qty_bread`
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.customer_id
HAVING `qty_cheese`  >= 2
    OR `qty_bread`   >= 5
```

Again, this is checking the "total" qty for a given customer and given product. If you just want to check for the existence of a row that has `qty >= n`, then replace the `SUM()` aggregate function with `MAX()`.

For each row returned from mytable, we're evaluating an expression, comparing `product` to a specific value, and if it matches, we're returning the value from the `qty` column.

We typically do this in the SELECT list, just because it allows us to debug the query, we can leave off the "HAVING" clause, and get the list of all customers, and see the `qty` for each product.

It's not necessary that these expressions be in the SELECT list. These expressions could be moved to the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT t.customer_id
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.customer_id
HAVING SUM(IF(t.product= 'cheese'  ,t.qty,NULL))  >= 2
    OR SUM(IF(t.product= 'bread'   ,t.qty,NULL))  >= 5
```

---

There are a couple of other viable approaches.